# Angular 4 Toggle Stylesheets inside angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, stylesheet

Im wondering if its possible to toggle a theme ( 2 stylesheets ).
my actual config is stylesheet A inside my angular-cli.json config.
what i would like to do is to replace the stylesheet A with Stylesheet B with a simple (click) toggler.

if i would import the stylesheet in the index.html the code would look like this

Component:

```
constructor() { }

  toggleTheme() {
    this.darkTheme = this.lightTheme;
  }
```

Index.html

```
<div [class.dark]="darkTheme">
<div [class.light]="lightTheme">
<button (click)="toggleTheme()">
Toggle theme
</button>
```

but since im importing the stylesheet dark.css in the angular-cli.json file instead of the index.html , how could i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In angular every component has his own stylesheet file  and the scope is only for the component. I think you want to change the main Stylesheet in Index file, but it doesn't have context or scope to be changed since Angular component.

You can do it in your main component (as a shared Layout). But remember any children component won't have the stylesheet scope.

Comment: is there anything i could do to solve this? for example import it instead in the global css using the @import statement , but how would that work to toggle it im there ?